# Getting aws transcribe responses before Lambda Function times out

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-transcribe

I hava a AWS Lambda function written in Java. This function starts a TranscriptionJob and then wait for the response like so:

```
while( true ){
    transcriptionJob = awsClient.getTranscriptionJob(getJobRequest).getTranscriptionJob();
    if( transcriptionJob.getTranscriptionJobStatus().equals(TranscriptionJobStatus.COMPLETED.name()) ){
        System.out.println("AWS transcribe completed with " + transcriptionJob.getMedia().getMediaFileUri());
        Date comleption = transcriptionJob.getCompletionTime();
        // duration until response in seconds 
        long duration = (comleption.getTime()-awsTranscribeStart.getTime())/1000;
        logger.log("AWS transcribe took " + duration + " seconds\n");
        break;
    }else if( transcriptionJob.getTranscriptionJobStatus().equals(TranscriptionJobStatus.FAILED.name()) ){
        System.out.println("AWS transcribe failed: " + transcriptionJob.getFailureReason());
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For my longer audio files, a transcription job takes up to 10 minutes to be completed but a Lambda function is limited to 5 minutes.
There is no "Transcription job completed event" or something similiar(yet).

Is there a workaround for this problem or do I have to switch from AWS Lambda to something else?

Comment: It looks like the TranscriptFileUri in the eventual response points at a bucket that AWS Transcribe owns, rather than you own, so you can't trigger Lambda from the JSON response file being uploaded there. So, a couple of options would be to run a 2nd Lambda on a schedule that simply queries the job state for completion and then initiates your next action. Or, better still, you could build this simple workflow using Step Functions.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will try step functions and update my results here.

Comment: You can use step functions to orchestrate a longer running workflow or compose lambda functions together,

Answer (score 2):

I created a workaround using Step Functions.

[image]

There is another [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=279625) about this issue on the aws forum.